# How to handle a mutation after a webhook is received in Apollo / GraphQL

Tags: express, graphql, apollo

I came across implementation of webhooks in express my server and I would like to know how can I access mutations after a hook is received.

So in my case I receive hook from MangoPay when a payment is received. What I want to do is to update the MangoDB object.

Here I am getting the hook

```
app.use("/api/mangopay/webhooks", (res) => {
  console.log(res.query);
  res.status(200).send("ok");
});
```

the `res.query` look like this

```
{ RessourceId: '68127571',
  EventType: 'PAYIN_NORMAL_SUCCEEDED',
  Date: '1567382400' }
```

Now the question is can I access Mutations from here or shall I create new resolvers for each type of hook?